# How do I use user inputted parameter as reference in Fn:Join in the resource section of AWS Cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
{

    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  
    "Parameters": {
        "EnterIpAddress":{
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resource":{
        "XyZ":{
            "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
            "ContainerDefinitions": [
                {
                    "Command": [

                        
                        {
                          "Fn::Join": [
                            "=", [
                              "--beacon_ip",
                              {
                                "Ref": "EnterIpAddress"
                              }
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    
}
```

I want to use the parameter as a reference in Fn::Join so that my final output would be

```
"--beacon_ip=xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
```

Where I want the user to input the IP address(xx.xxx.xxx.xx)

But I'm getting this error on uploading the template to the stack:

```
Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [EnterIpAddress] in the Resources block of the template
```

Please tell me how do I achieve the desired output. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you haven't posted your entire stack, could it just be a typo somewhere? As far as I can tell, the syntax looks correct, but since it's an abbreviated version of the CloudFormation file, there might be some error in there that's not visible.

That being said, I do prefer the use of `Fn::Sub` over the use of `Fn::Join`, simply because it makes it easier to interpret as a reader of the CloudFormation file:

```json
{
  "Fn::Sub": "--beacon_ip=${EnterIpAddress}"
}
```